# Parsing templates with variables and variable pairs with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have template files in my application that I would like to pare with jQuery. I cant do this server side so I have to do it with JS. In my script is an object that contains the variables that are supposed to be parsed with the specified values. If the value is an object(variable pair), the HTML between those tags gets duplicated for every iteration of that object.  Here is what I mean:

```
citizen_results = [
{
    firstname: "Elliot",
    lastname: "Stabler",
    dateofbirth: "12/01/70",
    sex: "M",
    height: "180cm",
    id: 1
  },
  {
    firstname: "Olivia",
    lastname: "Benson",
    dateofbirth: "03/15/78",
    sex: "F",
    height: "180cm",
    id: 2
  }
  {
    firstname: "John"
    lastname: "Munch",
    dateofbirth: "04/08/48",
    sex: "M",
    height: "180cm",
    id: 3
  }
]

data = {
    results: citizen_results,
    pagination: "<ul><li><a href="#">1</a></li></ul>'
}

parseTemplate('citizen-results.html', data);

function ParseTemplate(file, data){
        $.get('html/'+file, function(response){
            var contents = response
            Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key,index) {
                if(isObject(data[key])){
                    $.each(data[key], function(k, v){
                        
                    })
                } else {
                    contents.replace("{" + key + "}", data[key]);
                }
            })
        })
        $('#content-container').html(contents);
    }
function isObject(var item){
        return typeof item === 'object' && item !== null
    }
```

So my template file looks like this:

```
<div id="page-content">
    <h1>Citizens</h1>
    <div id="search-box">
        <h2>Search Citizens</h2>
        <input type="text" name="citizen_name">
    </div>
    {citizen_results}
    <div class="media">
        <div class="media-body">
            <h3>{firstname} {lastname}</h3>
            <ul class="media-meta">
                <li><i class="fa fa-child"></i>{height}</li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>{dateofbirth}</li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-mercury"></i>{sex}</li>
                <li><a href="#" data-event="loadCitizenProfile" data-resource-id="{id}"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    {/citizen_results}
    {pagination}
</div>
```

And the final result of the HTML should look like this:

```
<div id="page-content">
    <h1>Citizens</h1>
    <div id="search-box">
        <h2>Search Citizens</h2>
        <input type="text" name="citizen_name">
    </div>
    <div class="media">
        <div class="media-body">
            <h3>Elliot Stabler</h3>
            <ul class="media-meta">
                <li><i class="fa fa-child"></i>180cm</li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>12/01/70</li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-mercury"></i>M</li>
                <li><a href="#" data-event="loadCitizenProfile" data-resource-id="1"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media">
        <div class="media-body">
            <h3>Olivia Benson</h3>
            <ul class="media-meta">
                <li><i class="fa fa-child"></i>180cm</li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>03/15/78</li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-mercury"></i>F</li>
                <li><a href="#" data-event="loadCitizenProfile" data-resource-id="2"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media">
        <div class="media-body">
            <h3>John Munch</h3>
            <ul class="media-meta">
                <li><i class="fa fa-child"></i>180cm</li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>04/08//48</li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-mercury"></i>M</li>
                <li><a href="#" data-event="loadCitizenProfile" data-resource-id="3"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    </ul
</div>
```

I'm not really sure what to do with the code inside `$.each(data, function(k, v)`

Comment: If you need to do a lot of different versions in your site look at using a template script like handlebars.js or more modern framework like React, Vue, Angular etc

Comment: I've given handlebars.js a try but it keeps giving me an unrecognized expression error with the HTML i wrote above. Any idea why? the html looks fine to me

Comment: Not without seeing the syntax modified to match handlebars expected syntax